# Why argument accept "text" but not string variable?

Tags: c++, mbed, bbc-microbit

I am trying to combine integers x y z from an accelerometer on microbit into a string and then send it to serial port. I am using c++ in online mbed compiler here with the microbit DAL library.

```
uBit.init();
uBit.serial.baud(115200);

MicroBitI2C i2c = MicroBitI2C(I2C_SDA0, I2C_SCL0); 
MicroBitAccelerometer accelerometer = MicroBitAccelerometer(i2c);




while(1) {

    int x=uBit.accelerometer.getX();
    int y=uBit.accelerometer.getX();
    int z=uBit.accelerometer.getX();

    stringstream result;
    result << x << "," << y << "," << z;
    uBit.serial.send(result.c_str());
    uBit.serial.send("\r\n");
}
```

however the result.c_str() gave me an error of Error: Class "std::basic_stringstream, std::allocator>" has no member "c_str" in "main.cpp", Line: 26, Col: 34
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXhD1.jpg)

Comment: Type the code in the question.

Comment: `result.c_str()`

Comment: please post your code instead of its screenshot

Comment: Why are you using `sprintf` instead of `std::to_string`?

Comment: sorry this is my first post in stackflow:) wil change now

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That probably is because the method `send` only takes a `const char*` as argument and not a std::string. Try:

`uBit.serial.send(result.c_str());`

edit:

Now your code has changed and result is a stringstream:

`uBit.serial.send(result.str().c_str())`.

Comment: sorry its not working..  it says Error: Class "std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>" has no member "c_str" in "main.cpp", Line: 26, Col: 34

Comment: Did you really enter `result.c_str()` and not `result.c_str`?

Comment: nope.. i just updated the question yea i used result.c_str() but still not correct

Comment: See my updated answer then.

Comment: thanks! now no lines is marked as error but tons of alerts saying ..Error: No space in execution regions with .ANY selector matching https://imgur.com/a/Wr0WQ

Comment: The problem seems to be that your target has not enough RAM for what you are trying to do: http://www.keil.com/forum/19067/
Please accept my answer as the solution to your initial problem if it indeed solved it. Thanks!

Comment: thanks.. it solved the script problem but doesnt work on my hardware.... i feel bad to approve this answer but yes u are right u have answered it..

Comment: Well you can still ask a new question with your new problem if you want an answer, but probably on another place (like maybe superuser.com), this is not in stackexchange scope.